# How to read the contents of a XML file and save it in a javascript variable as string?

Tags: javascript, xml, string, variables

I'm trying to load the contents of a simple xml file and save it as a string variable in javascript. Here's the contents of the simple xml: `hello world.` 
Ultimately, I wanna save it as a string in a variable named `xmlDoc` and do some manipulations.
So what I did was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","testing.xml",false);
xhttp.send();

var xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

document.write(xmlDoc);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of `"hello world."`, `[object Document]` was printed on my html page. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving an `XHRResponse` object, not just the string. If you `console.log()` the xmlDoc and have a look at it, you'll find that it has more properties. You're probably looking for the `.data` property or something similar.

i.e., `xhttp.responseXML.data`;

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it was an object, but couldn't figure out what to do with it. It turns out `xhttp.responseText` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

use responseText attribute

```
var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseText;
```

responseText -> get the response data as a string

responseXML ->  get the response data as XML data

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp